# Magento 2 - Copy price block to another location in product layout

Tags: magento2

I am trying to find a way to duplicate the price block so that it appears in two locations of the product page for specific products, by using the *Layout Update XML* field inside the design tab of the product edit page (Magento Admin).

I have successfully copied the price block by creating a modified layout XML file for specific products, for example:

```
theme_folder\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_product_view_id_178.xml
```

Inside this file I added the following in the required location:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.final.second.location" after="product.info.options.wrapper">
<arguments>
<argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
<argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">final_price</argument>
<argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_view</argument>
</arguments>
</block>
```

However there are too many products that use this modified layout and it would be easier to manage the product catalog if I could achieve the same thing just using the *Layout Update XML* field and entering a simple instruction like:

```
<copy element="product.price.final" destination="second.price.container">
```

Except there is no *copy* instruction, only a *move* instruction which is not what I want.

A different solution would be to have a way to select which layout XML to use from the product edit page, for example a yes/no attribute.

Is there a way to achieve this result?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The following XML inserted into the *Layout Update XML* field will copy the price block to a referenceBlock (or referenceContainer):

```
<referenceBlock name="my.reference.block">
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.final.lower">
<arguments>
<argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
<argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">final_price</argument>
<argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_view</argument>
</arguments>
</block>
</referenceBlock>
```